# Making nginx change parameter in url

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

how I can change parameters in url
e.g `https://example.com/r.php?12345` to `https://example.com/12345` ?

nginx conf file :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;
    rewrite_log on;
    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    } 
}
```

and where to add the block 
inside the conf file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final element of `try_files` is the default action if the URI does not map to a local file. So replace your 404 error with the desired rewrite. Try:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /r.php?$uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.